# Convert to date

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to create number of Evenement instances and set the date for them:

```
   for (int i=2004; i<2009; i++){
           evenementen.add(new Evenement("Rock Werchter", "Rock", "Werchter", 200000,
                           (Date)formatter.parse(i+"/07/03")));
```

But I can't seem to get it to work,

Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong?
What is Evenement class?
How has been initialized formatter?

Show us more code!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use Calendar to create your dates.

```
for (int i=2004; i<2009; i++) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.clear();
    // Calendar.JULY may be different depending on the JDK language
    cal.set(i, Calendar.JULY, 3); // Alternatively, cal.set(i, 6, 3); 
    evenementen.add(new Evenement("Rock Werchter", "Rock", "Werchter", 200000,
            cal.getTime()));
}
```

Note that the months are zero-based, so July is 6.

Answer (score 2):

Beware of the locale used for the date formatter (default can be `Locale.ENGLISH` is your OS is set that way, meaning the year is at the end, not at the beginning of the string)

You need to be sure to have a formatter build as (at the time of writing, 2008, Java6, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51615452/6309)):

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/DD");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default for the date formatter is whatever you've got your operating system set to.

Comment: The code is wrong. I tried parsing `2004/07/03` (the first string from the question) with your formatter, expected 3 July 2004, but got `Sat Jan 03 00:00:00 CET 2004`.

Comment: @OleV.V. 13 years later, something might have changed indeed. I was using Java 6 at the time. Let me read your own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67742568/6309 and educate myself.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 2004; i < 2009; i++) {
            System.out.println(LocalDate.of(i, Month.JULY, 3));
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do it by parsing the string (the way you have posted in the question), use `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u/M/d", Locale.ENGLISH);
        for (int i = 2004; i < 2009; i++) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(i + "/07/03", dtf);
            System.out.println(date);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2004-07-03
2005-07-03
2006-07-03
2007-07-03
2008-07-03
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>